# mediawiki-api - links on page & getting fields on those pages

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

If I have a wikimedia category such as "Category:Google_Art_Project_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh", is there an API to retrieve a list of the URLs linked to on that page?

I've tried this, but it doesn't return any links: [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Category:Google_Art_Project_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh&prop=links](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Category%3aGoogle_Art_Project_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh&prop=links)

(If not, I'll parse the html and obtain them that way.)

Once I have all the URLs linked to, is there an API to retrieve some of the information on the page?  (Summary/Artist, Title, Date, Dimensions, Current location, Licensing)

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to have a way to return that information: [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Irises-Vincent_van_Gogh.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File%3aIrises-Vincent_van_Gogh.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there an API to retrieve a list of the URLs linked to on that page?

I guess you're looking for the [Categorymembers API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aCategorymembers) which will list the pages in the selected category.

> I've tried this, but it doesn't return any links: [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Category:Google_Art_Project_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh&prop=links](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Category%3aGoogle_Art_Project_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh&prop=links)

First, notice that [this is a Wikimedia Commons Category](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aGoogle_Art_Project_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh), querying the `en.wikipedia.org` did return a you a `missing` page. However, even if you [query the right project](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Category%3aGoogle_Art_Project_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh&prop=links), you will notice that [the category description](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category%3aGoogle_Art_Project_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh&action=edit) does indeed not contain any links.

> Once I have all the URLs linked to, is there an API to retrieve some of the information on the page?

You can use the categorymembers query as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Generators), then specify the usual [properties](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties) that you want from each page. However, the metadata you seem to be interested in is not available via the API, you need to parse it out of each image description text.

Try https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category%3aGoogle_Art_Project_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh&prop=links|imageinfo|revisions&iiprop=timestamp|user|url|size|mime&rvprop=ids|content&rvgeneratexml

Comment: Mean loading the "descriptionurl" given by API and parsing its HTML to obtain the metadata I need?  Or, if there's a way to get the image description text through the API -- albeit that it will still need to be parsed?  For example, [link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=File:Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg&iilimit=max&iiprop=timestamp|user|comment|url|size|mime&prop=imageinfo|revisions&rvgeneratexml=&rvprop=ids|timestamp|user|comment|content) doesn't contain "oil on canvas" like the discussion URL does. unless rvlimit=max and go way back

Comment: ... stackoverflow is interpreting that link as having internal italics because the link itself has (underscore)-(underscore).  Replacing "<i>Starry_Night</i>" with "(underscore)Starry_Night(underscore)" gets it back to how I attempted posting it.

Comment: The link you posted in your comment gives an invalid result. What do you mean by "discussion URL"? The query I presented does already provide you the source markup of each image description page, even the parser model (which should be more reliable than HTML output). See the [revision api](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#revisions_.2F_rv) for more information.

Comment: You mean [this query](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=File:Van%20Gogh%20-%20Starry%20Night%20-%20Google%20Art%20Project.jpg&iilimit=max&iiprop=timestamp|user|comment|url|size|mime&prop=imageinfo|revisions&rvgeneratexml=&rvprop=ids|timestamp|user|comment|content)? SO works well

Comment: "discussion URL" - I mean the page.imageinfo.ii attribute "descriptionurl" which gives the URL of the wikimedia page showing a thumbnail of the image, download links, and the "metadata" I'm after for that image.

Comment: That "description url" only seems to be relevant when you access the file [on a local repository like en.WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=File:Van%20Gogh%20-%20Starry%20Night%20-%20Google%20Art%20Project.jpg&iilimit=max&iiprop=timestamp|user|comment|url|size|mime&prop=imageinfo|revisions&rvgeneratexml=&rvprop=ids|timestamp|user|comment|content); however when already using the Commons API you've got exactly that page whose revisions you are viewing. It consists only of a few templates, though.

Comment: Yes, the query you posted doesn't return the information on the description url's Summary block -- like "Artist, Title, Data, Medium, Dimensions, etc."

Comment: Confused, does this mean there is no API way to obtain the information in the Summary block on the description page -- meaning to get that information, load the description page's HTML and parse it manually?

Comment: Well, usually it works quite well, but in this case the summary block is included in [a template](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Template:Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project). You really might need to resort to parsing [the html](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&pageids=25498286&prop=imageinfo|revisions&rvparse&rvprop=content) (or [wikitext](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&pageids=25498286&prop=imageinfo|revisions&rvexpandtemplates&rvprop=content)) then, if you don't want to expand the templates manually